# ngStyle color with true false ?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'color' : 'value == white', '!value == red' }">Hello</p>
```

Any idea on how to use NgStyle with true false value ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**[ngStyle]**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html) *directive* waits for an expression.

You can do something like this:

```
<p [ngStyle]="{ 'color': value }">Hello</p>
<!-- When the value is === 'red' the color red will be applied to <p> and so on... -->
```

Or...

```
<p [ngStyle]="{ 'color': (value ? 'white' : 'red') }">Hello</p>
```

And manipulate this `value` *variable* somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I would try like as follows:

```
<p [style.color] = "value ? 'white' : 'red'">Hello</p>
```

Here `value` is the expression

If `value = true` then white and if `value = false` then red.